# Request and response SOAP XML in a Django View

Tags: python, xml, django, django-views

I need to display in a template a XML file.
The xml file have a SOAP format and the structure is like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bbs:QueryCDRRequestMsg>
         <RequestHeader>
                <app:Version>1</app:Version>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <cbs:BusinessCode>1</cbs:BusinessCode>
                <cbs:MessageSeq>${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date())}</cbs:MessageSeq>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <cbs:OwnershipInfo>
                   <cbs:BEID>101</cbs:BEID>
                   <!--Optional:-->
                   <cbs:BRID>101</cbs:BRID>
                </cbs:OwnershipInfo>
                <cbs:AccessSecurity>
                   <cbs:LoginSystemCode>102</cbs:LoginSystemCode>
                   <cbs:Password>hfhfidETT3Dcvdgtuidm==</cbs:Password>
                   <cbs:RemoteIP>1.1.1.1</cbs:RemoteIP>
                </cbs:AccessSecurity>
                <cbs:TimeFormat>
                   <cbs:TimeType>1</cbs:TimeType>
                   <!--Optional:-->
                   <cbs:TimeZoneID>1</cbs:TimeZoneID>
                </cbs:TimeFormat>
            </RequestHeader>
         <QueryCDRRequest>
            <!--Optional:-->
             <bbs:SubAccessCode>
               <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
               <bbc:PrimaryIdentity>99999999</bbc:PrimaryIdentity>
               <bbc:SubscriberKey>9999999</bbc:SubscriberKey>
            </bbs:SubAccessCode>
            <bbs:TimePeriod>
               <bbs:StartTime>20150401010000</bbs:StartTime>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bbs:EndTime>20150425010000</bbs:EndTime>
            </bbs:TimePeriod>
         </QueryCDRRequest>
      </bbs:QueryCDRRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I don't need to show all the fields.
How can I read a SOAP XML file and pass it to the template where I will use a JQUERY snippet to show the xml as tree.

Some files are stored in a local folder, but others files will be accessed through a web service where I need to send a request like the above XML example.

In few words, how can I send and retrieve XML using SOAP format in a django view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your usecase where you want to display SOAP XML, but the XML is just a string.  Just send it as such.  Though, I would ask yourself why you want to display the SOAP, as its intended as a protocol to call functions and retrieve data.

Comment: to retrieve the data I need to send a request in SOAP format. and I am having problems to display the nodes of the XML.

Comment: If you're having trouble doing the SOAP request, you should use a SOAP module that will let you read in the WSDL file for that SOAP service.  That will essentially give you an object with functions to hit all the endpoints.  That way you are just using python functions instead of dealing with XML.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I will search some info about SOAP modules. And I think you are right I prefer deal with models or another python object than a XML file